# Adding a counting pattern

Tags: python

I need help figuring out how to complete step #3.. please.. the textbook that I'm using doesn't explain the counting function very well, it just shows this "len" function the way I have it coded below, which is incorrect.

1. Add an input() statement at the start of the program.  The input()
   should prompt the user for  a positive starting number.
2. Use the number keyed in by the user as the starting value for the for loop. 
   The loop should print all odd numbers between the number keyed in
   and that number's negative value.
3. Add a counter to the program *AND* print that count out at the end of the 
   program.

I was able to accomplish #'s 1 and 2, but I cannot get #3. Here's what I have so far...

```
    evenNumber = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
    for i in range (evenNumber-1, -evenNumber, -2):"
        print (i)
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(evenNumber),1):
        count += 1
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: What specifically do your you need help with for 3?

Comment: Is the intent for #3 to print the count of the odd numbers you're already displaying? If so, it appears you've added an unnecessary second loop. And I don't see that you print your counter anywhere.

Comment: Yes Fred, that is correct. Can you instruct me on how to add the print counter.

Comment: @Allison If `evenNumber` is a number, what are you expecting `len(evenNumber)` to do? It looks like you can just get rid of the call to `len`.

Comment: I think @Nathan has your answer. I'll note, however, that there is nothing  to make sure `evenNumber` is, in fact, an even number.

Comment: You are all AWESOME.. thank you sooo very much for the help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to count the amount of numbers printed?

```
evenNumber = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
count = 0
for i in range (evenNumber-1, -evenNumber, -2):
    count += 1
    print (i)
print(count)
```

Or as @Jean-François Fabre suggests

```
evenNumber = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
for i in range (evenNumber-1, -evenNumber, -2):
    print (i)
count = len(range(evenNumber-1, -evenNumber, -2))
print(count)
```

Comment: `count = len(range (evenNumber-1, -evenNumber, -2))` is probably faster

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you're right, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Allison Glad to hear :) Can you accept the answer?

Comment: reduces complexity a lot.

Comment: @Nathan can I message you directly?

Comment: @Allison sure, what about?

Comment: @Nathan About this same issue... how do I reach you?

Comment: @Allison you don't have enough points for a chat room. Perhaps it's easier to solve it here. What can I help you with?

Answer (score -1):

The formulation of the problem is a bit wonky. I'd assume you're supposed to count the steps your loop went through.

```
evenNumber = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
count = 0
for i in range(evenNumber-1, -evenNumber, -2):"
    print (i)
    count += 1
print(count)
```

There's a extra space after "range", BTW.